# TSQL First Non-Null value in Audit Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 that has the following data:

```
ID  ChangeDate               FName   MName  LName   Revision
1   2016-01-03 00:00:00.000  Ed      NULL   NULL    3
1   2016-01-02 00:00:00.000  NULL    David  NULL    2
1   2016-01-01 00:00:00.000  Joe     NULL   NULL    1   
2   2016-01-03 00:00:00.000  Michael NULL   NULL    2
2   2016-01-02 00:00:00.000  Henry   Jake   Smith   1
```

I need a tsql query that generates a single row with the most current output for each column:

```
ID FName    MName   LName
1  Ed       David   NULL 
2  Michael  Jake    Smith
```

Comment: How are `Jake` or `David` most current outputs for `MName`  column ?

Comment: Jake is the first non-null MName value for ID 2

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @MatBailie it's sql server 2014.  Added it to the question as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH
    sorted AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                               ORDER BY CASE WHEN FName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                                        Revision DESC
                          ) AS FNameOrdinal,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                               ORDER BY CASE WHEN MName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                                        Revision DESC
                          ) AS MNameOrdinal,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                               ORDER BY CASE WHEN LName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                                        Revision DESC
                          ) AS LNameOrdinal,
        *
    FROM
        yourTable
)
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN FNameOrdinal = 1 THEN FName ELSE NULL END)   AS FName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MNameOrdinal = 1 THEN MName ELSE NULL END)   AS MName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LNameOrdinal = 1 THEN LName ELSE NULL END)   AS LName
FROM
    sorted
GROUP BY
    id
```